# How to call pdb.gimp_pencil in Gimp Python-fu plugin

Tags: gimp, python-fu

I'm trying to automate the task of drawing lines with Gimp.

So I tried the scripting feature with no luck so far.

```
    >>>from pprint import pprint
    >>>img = gimp.Image(200, 200, RGB)
    >>>pprint (pdb.gimp_pencil.params)
    ((16, 'drawable', 'The affected drawable'), 
     (0,
       'num-strokes',
       'Number of stroke control points (count each coordinate as 2 points) (num-strokes >= 2)'),
     (8,
       'strokes',
       'Array of stroke coordinates: { s1.x, s1.y, s2.x, s2.y, ..., sn.x, sn.y }'))
    >>>pdb.gimp_pencil(img, 4, [0,0,200,200] )
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
    TypeError: wrong parameter type
```

I couldn't find any example of passing a vector (Array of stroke coordinates) in Python for Gimp

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Ok my mistake, I assumed the TypeError was on the last array argument. As it happens `img` is not the drawable, hence the TypeError.

You have to:

1. create an image
2. create a layer
3. add the layer to the image
4. set the layer active
5. obtain the active drawable of the image

Then only you can use this drawable in the `gimp_pencil()` method.

```
img = gimp.Image(200, 200, RGB)
layer = gimp.Layer(img, "Test", 200, 200, RGBA_IMAGE, 100, NORMAL_MODE)
img.add_layer(layer, -1)
pdb.gimp_image_set_active_layer(img, layer)
draw = pdb.gimp_image_get_active_drawable(img)
pdb.gimp_pencil(draw, 4, [0,0,100,100])
disp1 = gimp.Display(img)
```